# Many to Many relationship contactorder_association missing from Relationship Explorer

Tags: many-to-many, dynamics-crm-2013

Why is the many to many relationship (contactorder_association) not showing in the Relationship Explorer. I am an administrator of dynamics 2013 and have the role administrator assigned

In our old 2011 solution we are using this relationship to get the associated contacts list but cannot figure out how to add it to our CRM2013 solution

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the relationship to the form navigation because it is set to have *Display Option*: *Do not Display*.

This cannot be changed for the default relationship between Order and Contact (it appears that your Order has been renamed to Case, which to me seems like a strange choice).

[image: contactorders_association]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, In our old CRM 2011 we can access the contacts that have been linked via the contactorders_association in c# and accessed via a navigation link on the salesorder form, do you know how we could create a link to these contacts from the 2013 sales order form?

Comment: You could add a subgrid to the form showing associated contacts. How do you actually add the related contacts otherwise?

Comment: Fab thank you, I've added a sub grid and that works very well, not sure how it was setup in Dynamics 2011 but it's good to see the related contact on the Sales order screen